# Chain methods with UIViewRepresentable subclass

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiviewrepresentable

I'm trying to implement a UITextView using the following `UIViewRepresentable`

```swift
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct TextView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String
    var _editable : Bool = true

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let result = UITextView()
        let font = UIFont(name: "Menlo",size: 18)
        result.font = font

        return result
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = text
        uiView.isEditable = _editable
    }

    mutating func editable(_ editable: Bool) -> TextView {
        _editable = editable
        return self
    }
}
```

You will notice the mutating func `editable` that I would like to use in my SwiftUI struct like this :

```swift
        return ZStack(alignment: Alignment.trailing) {
            TextView(text: Binding($note.content)!)
                .editable(true) // <<<< Here
            VStack {
                Text(dateString)
                    .font(.caption)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                    .padding(3)
                Spacer()
            }
        }
```

But the following exception is thrown :

```
Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: function call returns immutable value
```

[image: Screenshot]

I suspect that `UIViewRepresentable` isn't mutable, and wondering if there is a way around it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These "chained methods" are not supposed to be mutating. If you look at the methods that you can chain in the SwiftUI framework, none of them are marked `mutating`. [Quick example](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/3276841-bold).

These methods are supposed to *return a new instance of the struct, with some property changed*.

i.e. like this:

```
func editable(_ editable: Bool) -> TextView {
    // This is a new instance of the struct, but _editable is changed to the new value
    TextView(text: $text, _editable: editable) 
}
```

Comment: Makes a lot of sense ! Thank you